# multiple dbs to read from, under jboss

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, sharding

I have a piece of j2EE app that runs on Jboss AS 4.2.3 and has a lot of reads to a mysql db.

I'd like to setup several more mysql instances, so the app will be able to decide which to contact.
we are using Hibernate as the ORM (full JPA support).

I've been looking at Hibernate Shards, and OpenJPA - but perhaps there is another way to do it?

is there a way we can still use JPA (so we won't need to change our code) and have some kind of read balancing as the provider?

I can pull some tricks on the hosts file, use a DNS with short TTL - but am looking for a simpler solution.

is there one?

just to make sure, sharding is not interesting at this point. just reading.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually what i did was to extend mysql jdbc driver and modified the mysql-ds.xml file.

in the xml file i changed the connection string to contain several hosts, and the :mysql: to :myjdbc:, and entered my class as the provider.

in the JDBC driver i extended i've had to parse the connection string in two functions:
1. acceptsURL
2. connect

my code parses the connection string, selects a machine randomly, and calls the super function with a revised legal connection string.

and it just worked!
if a mysql read replica failed, then the connection fails, and on the next attempt a different machine is chosen.

whooohooo!

do you have any comments?